# Embedded node-red in a feathersjs application get websocket error

Tags: websocket, node-red, feathersjs

I can embed node-red with a custom service with the following node-red.service.js :

```
// Initializes the `node-red` service on path `/red`
const { NodeRed } = require('./node-red.class');
const hooks = require('./node-red.hooks');
const RED = require("node-red");

module.exports = function (app) {

  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    paginate
  };

  // Create the node-red settings object
  const settings = {
    httpAdminRoot:"/red",
    httpNodeRoot: "/red",
    userDir:  "./red",
    functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
  };

  // Initialise the runtime with a server and settings
  RED.init(app,settings);

  // Serve the editor UI from /red
  app.use('/red' , RED.httpAdmin );
  RED.start()


};
```

If I go to localhost:3030/red I get the node-red page, but after few seconds it lost connection to server with the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3030/red/comms' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I think there is a problem serving thru websocket or maybe since /red/comms is not defined in feathersjs it can't connect. Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes with this line:

```
 // Initialise the runtime with a server and settings
  RED.init(app,settings);
```

As the comment says, you need to initialise the runtime with a *server* object. Here you are passing it an Express application, *not* a server.

It is not possible to mount websocket listeners on an express app - Node-RED needs access to the underlying HTTP Server object.

I am not familiar with what apis featherjs provides, but it does appear to allow you access to the http server object - for example by calling `app.listen` yourself - https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#app-listen-port